# Random error in code

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a function which has to search all pcs in the network and look for responses:

```
DLL void get_remote_ip(void)
{
    initWSA();
    if(create_Sockets() == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Socket Error\n";
        return;
    };
    initiate_TXRX_variables();
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp_server_search server(io_service);
    std::cout << "No crash till here\n";
    boost::thread thread_1 = boost::thread(ultra_spam_network_udp);
    boost::asio::deadline_timer dt1 = boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service);
    boost::thread thread_2(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
    dt1.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000));
    dt1.wait();
    //ip_adr_ccd = server.return_ip(0);
    if(ip_adr_ccd != "localhost" && ip_adr_daisy != "localhost")
    {
        std::cout << "Remote IP of CCD is: " << ip_adr_ccd << '\n';//For debug
        std::cout << "Remote IP of TERS is: " << ip_adr_daisy << '\n'; //For debug
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No new remote ips found\n";
    //std::cout << Use << '\n';
    //thread_1.join();
}
```

When I call this function, my program crashes sometimes without telling me why, it just tells me "Exception error in <hex-address>". Where is my bug? Is it possible that one thread tries to join, but the other one has not finished now (which can be possible because the errors are quite random and are killing the std::cout-output of the main thread within writing)?
Thank you!

Comment: *(a)* errors are not random, especially if they're repeated *(b)* I've never seen "heavy exception error" messages in my life. *(c)* If it says "heavy exception error in " - I'd say the ***very next words*** are pretty relevant ... :|

Comment: @(a)These errors appear for me quite random., @(c): Some error messages: Exception error at 0x002A7D7F in RunDLL.exe, if I change something in my DLL or my calling exe, the hex code is changing, too.

Comment: The only objective thing you can say is "they don't appear consistently on every run". The percieved randomness is very subjective. As for the "heavy exception error": googling for it suggests you just might have mistranslated the German phrase "schwerer Ausnahmefehler" - which is better translated as "fatal exception error".

Comment: @ArneMertz: Yes, I think this was a mistake of mine. I think I narrowed the problem towards thread 2, if I call `thread_2.join()`, I get no error, but my program never finishes, when I do not call this, my program crashes sometimes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake, I have to stop `io_service` first and then call `thread_2.join()`, otherwise my thread_2 is crashing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to stop the `io_service` in a clean way. `io_serice::run` blocks while there are ramining handlers to be dispatched. My guess is that your `udp_server_search` causes an endless queueing of handlers. So either your join never finishes because it has to wait for the `run()` to return which never happens, or if you comment it out, leaving `get_remote_ip` will destroy the `io_service` while in `thread_2` the `run` method continues to be executed on a now destroyed object.

What could solve your problem (besides from breaking the endless queue on the server) is manually stopping the ioservice:

```
boost::thread thread_2( [&]{io_service.run();} );
//do stuff, wait for the timer etc...

io_service.stop(); //run should return as soon as possible
thread_2.join(); //clean finishing of the service.
```